# Событийная модель

Tags: события

есть два типа классов Учитель и Студент
нужно, что бы учитель знал, что студент пришёл на лекцию

как реализовать, какой из классов (учитель/ученик) должен содержать событие, а какой подписываться на это событие?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно поставленная задача-50% решения.

Собственно, в вопросе сразу же дан ответ.

Ученик приходит=> генерит событие.

Как следствие, ученик должен содержать событие, а преподаватель быть подписанным на событие от ученика.

Когда ученик приходит, то уведомляет учителя о своем приходе и учитель теперь знает об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокод:

```
    class Teacher {
        List<Student> list; //журнал посещаемости конкретного учителя
        ...
        addStudent(Student st) 
            => list.add(st);
    }

    class Student{
        event ev;

        onStudent(){
            ... //я пришёл на пару
            ev?.Invoke(this); //по предмету ev
            ... //учусь
        }   
    }
```

и где-то там мы подписываемся

```
student.ev += teacher.addStudent;
```

так или как? :)